# How to update stock in 2nd table

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have 2 table.
this is structure my table

table 1 with name `tbl_mobo`
[image: tbl_mobo]

table 2  with name `tr_mobo`

[image: tr_mobo]

1. I can input on ex: `tmbh_mobo`  on `table 2`it will sum active record on `table 1` `qty_available_mobo` and `qty_fisik_mobo`.
2. If I input `pnjam_mobo` on `table 2` it will - `qty_fisik_mobo` and + `qty_alocated_mobo`
3. I want to input `kbali_mobo` it will - `qty_alocated_mobo` and + `qty_fisik_mobo`

Please give me best way for it.

My controller

```
    public function create_action() 
{
    $this->_rules();

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->create();
    } else {
        $data = array(
    'tmbh_mobo' => $this->input->post('tmbh_mobo',TRUE),
    'pnjam_mobo' => $this->input->post('pnjam_mobo',TRUE),
    'kbali_mobo' => $this->input->post('kbali_mobo',TRUE),
    );
        $mobo = $this->input->post('merk', TRUE);
        $av_mobo = $this->input->post('tmbh_mobo', TRUE);
        $al_mobo = $this->input->post('pnjam_mobo', TRUE);

        $this->M_mobo->av_mobo($mobo,$av_mobo,$al_mobo);
        $this->M_trmobo->insert($data);
    }
}
```

My Model table 2 (M_mobo)

```
function av_mobo($mobo, $av_mobo, $al_mobo) { 
$this->db->set('qty_available_mobo', 'qty_available_mobo + ' . (int) $av_mobo, FALSE);
$this->db->set('qty_fisik_mobo', 'qty_fisik_mobo + ' . (int) $av_mobo, FALSE);
$this->db->set('qty_alocated_mobo', 'qty_alocated_mobo + ' . (int) $al_mobo, FALSE);
$this->db->set('qty_fisik_mobo', 'qty_fisik_mobo - ' . (int) $al_mobo, FALSE);

$this->db->where('tipe_mobo', $mobo);
$this->db->update('tbl_mobo');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a conditional out of it. These will update only the required field on each of those case :

```
function av_mobo($mobo, $av_mobo, $al_mobo) { 
    if (!empty($av_mobo)) { // if ditambah
        $this->db->set('qty_available_mobo', 'qty_available_mobo + ' . (int) $av_mobo, FALSE);
        $this->db->set('qty_fisik_mobo', 'qty_fisik_mobo + ' . (int) $av_mobo, FALSE);
    }
    if (!empty($al_mobo)) { // if dipinjam
        $this->db->set('qty_alocated_mobo', 'qty_alocated_mobo + ' . (int) $al_mobo, FALSE);
        $this->db->set('qty_fisik_mobo', 'qty_fisik_mobo - ' . (int) $al_mobo, FALSE);
    }

    $this->db->where('tipe_mobo', $mobo);
    $this->db->update('tbl_mobo');
    return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

then only do insert if `tbl_mobo` data is updated, change :

```
$this->M_mobo->av_mobo($mobo,$av_mobo,$al_mobo);
$this->M_trmobo->insert($data);
```

to :

```
if ($this->M_mobo->av_mobo($mobo,$av_mobo,$al_mobo) == TRUE)
{
    $this->M_trmobo->insert($data);
}
```